# スタック・オーバーフローコミュニティのYouTubeチャンネル開設についてあなたの考えをお聞かせ下さい

Tags: 討議

翻訳をしてくれた[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)に感謝します。

---

チャットの [SOja交流会部屋](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95328/soja) で最近、payaneco さん、nekketsuuu さん、そしてakiと私でYouTubeコミュニティチャンネルについて少しだけ話す機会がありました。そこから、私たちスタック・オーバーフローで必要とされるテクニカルな面を確認し、ここにYouTubeチャンネル開設が可能であることをお知らせいたします。

そこで、皆さんにいくつか質問があります。

1. YouTubeにスタック・オーバーフローコミュニティチャンネルを開設したいですか？
2. チャンネルではどのような動画を好んで見てみたいですか？
3. 動画の作成に興味がありますか？ ある場合、どのような動画を作りたいですか？

個人的には、メインサイトでの技術的な質問や回答を補足するためのYouTubeチャンネル開設は優れた方法だと思っています。このチャンネルでは、コミュニティの動画配信、Q&Aのスクリーンキャストなど、あらゆる種類の動画をホストすることができます。唯一の制限はただ一つ、動画はスタック・オーバーフローコミュニティに関するものでなければならないということです。

YouTubeチャンネルについて考えがございましたらどうぞお知らせください。一緒に話し合い、決断しましょう。

Comment: チャットを見ても「代理でYouTubeにアップロードする」くらいの話しか出ておらず、何がクリアになったのかよく分かりません。"コミュニティ" 側の意見としてどちらかと言えば消極的に見えたのですが、このアイデアは"誰"発信なのでしょうか？ / Stack Exchange Network の中で、同様の取り組みをしているサイトはありますか？もしあるなら具体的にどのようなコンテンツをアップロードしており、取り組みはうまく機能していますか？

Comment: @cubick There are no other sites that do that. This is a very unique for Stack Overflow in Japanese. Although [on SOru we have a channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwwnMkw2Lok36TtjEVd7uqQ). I hope to hear what content would be interesting to you all. / 他のサイトでは特に行っておりません。日本語版のスタック・オーバーフロー独自のものになります。[SOruにはチャンネル](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwwnMkw2Lok36TtjEVd7uqQ)が存在するのですが。皆さんにとってどのようなコンテンツがよいのか是非おうかがいしたいです。

Comment: 暫く考えてみたのですが、YouTube チャンネルを何のために開設するのかがまだよく分かっていません。目的が決まれば、どんな動画がアップロードできそうか考えることができます。何のためのチャンネルにするのが良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR;

チャンネルに動画が投稿されれば拝見します。
**動画によるIT技術の発信/学習を希望する参加者**の間で盛り上がってほしいとも願っています。
しかしどのように参加すれば貢献できるのか、チャンネルが盛り上がるのか具体的な活用方法がよく分かりません。

なので私は消極的賛成です。

#### 前書き

回答する前に、チャットの会話を補足します。
YouTubeコミュニティチャンネルの話題がSOja交流会部屋に上がった経緯です。

SOja交流会はもくもく会に限らず複数回開催され、成功してきました。
SOja交流会では毎回テーマを掲げて常に新しいことに挑戦し続けています。
そしてSOja交流会を開くために、スタッフの皆さんがチャットルームで積極的に日程やテーマを提案してくださっています。

チャットルーム『SOja交流会部屋』で今までのSOjaにない新しい挑戦として、もくもく会の途中でライブ動画によるライトニングトーク(LT)をするという案が出ました。
ライブ動画に関連してスタッフからYouTbeコミュニティチャンネルというものがあると話題が上がりました。

しかし結局チャットの結果、第3回もくもく会でLTをするのは難しそうだと判断しました。
動画を募集したり作成するには次回の日程が近すぎて厳しいと予想されるからです。

#### 回答

> 1. YouTubeにスタック・オーバーフローコミュニティチャンネルを開設したいですか？

消極的賛成です。

まず私は動画を観る習慣がありません。
なので技術者向けのコミュニティチャンネルが想像できません。
そのためチャンネルの活用方法が分からないので「積極的に参加してガンガン使いたい！」と断言できないのです。
一言で言うと「若者の流行についていけないおじいちゃん」です。(sigh)

> 2. チャンネルではどのような動画を好んで見てみたいですか？

私は動画を観る習慣がないので、自信はありませんが「文字で説明できない操作が多い回答」動画が好まれると思います。
例えば下記のセットアップやIoTなどです。(これらの質問がオントピックかどうかの議論は、ここではオフトピックにさせてください)

- 「pythonのAnacondaをインストールして、pipのライブラリを読み込むまでのセットアップ手順」
- 「Spresenseに温度計を接続して定期的に出力する方法」

GUIや機材の操作が質問に出た時に、文字で手順を書き出したり画像を大量に用意して回答するのは大変です。
回答者が「当たり前にやっている操作」が説明されず、初心者にわかりにくいケースもあります。
それよりも、動画で見せた方が幅広い技術者に分かりやすい回答になります。

私が見たいのは、一時停止しながら操作を指さし確認できる動画、言い換えれば手順マニュアル動画かと想像しています。

> 3. 動画の作成に興味がありますか？ ある場合、どのような動画を作りたいですか？

私は技術者向けの動画作成をしたことがほとんどありません。
(でも「IoTでガジェットを作ってみた」動画を作ってみたことがあるので、とても簡単な動画は作れます)

しかし仮に交流会のLTで動画を作る機会があるならば、「ライブ回答」や「SOjaの統計調査」をテーマに挑戦すると思います。

Google検索結果を織り交ぜた回答をしたところ、質問者さんから「どうすればこういう回答をできるようになりますか」とコメント質問されたことがあります。
スコアの高い回答者は「英訳して検索」「キーワードを変えて検索」などのノウハウを持っています。
そのノウハウは回答者には当然のことかもしれませんが、プログラム初心者には高度で価値のある作業かもしれません。
なので私のノウハウが価値あるものかは知りませんが、恥ずかしながら作業風景というか調査手順を公開すると誰かの役に立てるかもと思うことがあります。

年々フレームワークの流行が変わることで質問の傾向も変わってきます。
例えば「SOjaの統計調査」で「AIの質問数は5年間でどれだけ増えたか」などを発表すると、日本での技術傾向を可視化できます。
SOja交流会部屋でTLのテーマに提案しましたが、[Developer Survey Results 2019](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019)はSOのアンケートをまとめてものすごく有益な技術情報に編集したものです。
有識者が質問のクエリなどを元にご自身の見識をまとめた動画は非常に興味があります。
おっと、こちらは作りたい動画ではなく見たい動画になってしまいました。

#### まとまってないまとめ

今回のご質問は「交流会やLTでコミュニティチャンネルを使いたいですか？」から発展して「SOjaユーザは動画という新しいコンテンツでQAサイトを発展させたいですか？」という問いに派生した、他のQAサイトにない挑戦的な提案だと勝手に思っています。
(最初に書いた経緯と質問文から、そう判断しました)

残念ながら私はデジタルネイティブではなく、動画というコンテンツの活用方法も一般常識もよく分かりません。
なので「コミュニティチャンネルに賛成したいけど動画の使い方も作るスキルもないから尻すぼみになってる」セルフでマサカリを投げる回答になってしまいました。

自分の持っている知識で活用方法を回答してみましたが、ライブ配信?やスパチャ???など時節に合った機能をご存知の有識者の方からご回答があれば、是非ともうかがいたいです。

P.S. 読みやすい日本語に直そうとしましたが無理でした。明快な回答になっておらず申し訳ありません。