# 2023 モデレーター選挙 Q&A - 質問リスト

Tags: 討議, 選挙

> **この投稿の目的は、2023年度モデレーター選挙で使われるための質問をコミュニティから集めることでした。現在、質問リストは公開されており、[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/2#questionnaire)から確認することができます。**

---

スタック・オーバーフローでは、[来週 2023-05-17 JST / 16 UTC](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/2) から選挙が予定されています。これに伴い、立候補者との質疑応答を行います。コミュニティメンバーが立候補者にモデレーションについての質問をする良い機会になります。参加は完全に任意です。

詳細は以下の通りです：

- 立候補の段階まで（つまり 2023-05-17 午前 5:00 (JST)、2023-05-16 午後 8:00 (UTC)まで）質問を受け付けます。本質問リストは、サイトユーザーから潜在的な質問を集めるためのものです。候補者に回答してほしい質問をぜひこちらに投稿してください。*1つの質問を回答ごとに*投稿してください。
- 質問にリンクが含まれている場合は、完成版の質問リストをスムーズに転記できるよう`[テキスト](リンク)`の構文を使用してください。
- この機会にあなたのコミュニティが直面している課題についてどうぞお聞かせください。
- 私たちコミュニティチームは一般的な質問をする予定で、質問リストには次の2つの必須の質問が含まれます：

  - あるユーザーが、品質が高い回答を続けて投稿している一方で、コメントで多数の言い争いや通報を引き起こしている場合、どのように対処しますか？
  - クローズ/削除されるべきではないとあなたが思った質問を、別のモデレーターがクローズ/削除したという状況に、どのように対処しますか？
- コミュニティから十分な数の質問を得られなかった場合、コミュニティチームは次の3つの質問を含める予定です。

  - あなたの意見では、モデレーターとは具体的に何をするのでしょう？
  - 質問や回答、コメントなど過去に発言したものすべての横にダイヤモンドマークが加えられ、これから発言することに対してもフィルターがかかります。そのような状況についてどう思いますか？
  - 単に [モデレーターツールへのアクセス (2,000)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) 或いは [信頼できるユーザー (4,000)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) の信用度に達するというのではなく、あなたはモデレーターになることによってさらにどのように効果的になると思いますか？
- 立候補の段階が始まる時、コミュニティチームは前述の2つの必須の質問に加えて、本投稿で**コミュニティによってプラス票が多く集められた上位8つの質問**を選択します。質問の選択には編集上の管理を留保し、内容が脱線したもの、モデレーションや選挙に関係のない質問を選択しない場合もあります。合計スコアがマイナスになっている質問は除外されます。

  - 最終的な質問リストは [選挙ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1) に掲載されます。候補者は質問リストに記載するオプションがあり、回答は紹介文の下に表示されます。
  - これはユーザーが候補者に関する情報を収集するための唯一の選択肢というわけではありません。コミュニティとして、例えば、候補者とのライブチャットセッションでさらに質問し、Q&A の内容についての説明を得ることもできるでしょう。

このプロセスについて質問やフィードバックがある場合は、どうぞお気軽にコメントとして投稿してください。

**参考:**

英語版における 2021 年モデレーター選挙の質問リスト (候補)
[2021 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411988)
実際に確定した質問は [こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13#questionnaire)

Comment: 去年の選挙で[質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3704/9820)を提案しました。この質問とすごく似ている質問を、今回また提案しても良いですか？

Comment: @payaneco  大丈夫です、質問をお待ちしております！

Comment: レスポンスありがとうございます。承知しました。

Answer (score 4):

モデレータには[人間例外処理機](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)の役割が与えられ、機械的な定型作業では対応できないスパムや問題を含む投稿に対応することが求められます。
ところで昨今、[New blog post from our CEO Prashanth: Community is the future of AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388401/)で議論の俎上に載りましたようにAIチャットは著しく進化を遂げており、投稿内容に応じて非定型の回答を生成可能です。
上記を踏まえて質問です。もしもあなたが他のユーザから「**人間のモデレータは不要**だ。高性能なAIチャットを用意し、[コミュニティBot](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/)にモデレータ権限を与えれば事足りる。AIチャットは浜の真砂を超える数の投稿を瞬時に、平等に、冷静にフォローアップできるのだから」と提案された時、どのように回答しますか？

Answer (score 2):

スタック・オーバーフローでは交流会やもくもく会など[様々な企画](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3704/9820)が催されてきました。そして[YouTubeチャンネル開設](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3491/9820)など、新たな挑戦も検討してきました。あなたはこういったこメイン掲示板にとどまらない**企画や挑戦**に対して、どのような思いを抱いているか教えてください。
モデレータが企画等に関与する義務はありませんが、モデレータの持つ意見やスタンスの影響は大きいと質問者は確信しています。例えば、推進したい！傍観する。新企画構想中など、ご自身のスタンスを交えてお答えいただけると個人的に嬉しいです。